# Is it possible to get sound generated from flash in web audio api?

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Hello all :) The question is pretty much the title.

A page has a flash application, which I cannnot touch, modify, reproduce in any way. I can put javascript in the page though. I can put another flash app also too.

Would it be possible to get the sound produced by the flash application, in the [brand new shiny Web Audio API](http://caniuse.com/audio-api)?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Not reliably, no. Flash applets are really not compatible with web technologies.

Comment: Thank you. You say not reliably, are you thinking of a specific roundabout way?

Comment: I'm thinking of a massive hack where you leverage the fact that some audio software and sound card allow to get the mixed down output of the computer as an input channel. But this is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no

Long answer: What audio format is the flash application producing? is it live sound or recorded?
What you would need is for the flash application to record the sound in a compatible format for the browser you are targeting and produce a blob out of it. From the blob you can create an object url in JS and feed it to the web audio API. Problem is to produce the blob from the flash app and make it available to the browser in a compatible format and I am not aware of any flash API that could do that.

A pushy workaround would be to send the recorded audio to a server to be transcoded and then hosted so that the web audio API can ingest this audio file.

Here is a good article to [start with the web audio API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)

Best option would be to go 100% flash free but it does not seem to fit your project requirements.